# mouse event in opencv c++

Tags: c++, events, mouse, geometry

I want to write a program with this feature:

> When a user click left button of mouse on windows a circle is
>   constructed with 15 radius

at first I make a black image 500*500

then I use `setMouseCallback` for `my_mouse_callback` and in function `my_mouse_callback` I write my circle code, when run the program there aren't any errors but only there is a black image 500*500 that when I click left button of mouse nothing happens, I know my program has trouble but where? please help me my program is like this:

```
void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);

int main() {
    int i,j,k;

    Mat image;
    image.create(500,500,CV_8UC3);

    namedWindow("amin");

    for(i=0;i<500;i++){
        for(j=0;j<500;j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                Vec3b &intensity = image.at<vec3b>(j, i);
                intensity.val[k]=0; 
            }
        } 
    } 

    setMouseCallback( "amin", my_mouse_callback, &image );

    imshow("amin",image);
    waitKey(0);

    return(0); 
} 

void my_mouse_callback( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param ) {
    if(event==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        circle( image, Point(x,y), 20, Scalar(0xff,0xff,0xff) );
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that your program "has trouble." what trouble? what is the exact problem? How does it compare to what you want?

Comment: after running only i have black image 500by500 that when i click left button nothin happens.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be OpenCV something I haven't used but:

The image variable surely isn't accessible from the my_mouse_callback function - it is local to main() ? Do you mean:

```
void my_mouse_callback( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param ) {
    if(event==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        Mat* pImage = (Mat*)param;
        Mat image = *pImage;
        circle( image, Point(x,y), 20, Scalar(0xff,0xff,0xff) );
    }
}
```

If this answer is stupid I appologise but I haven't used CV and this is the result of 30 seconds documentation reading.

Answer (score 0):

When I use opencv with version 2.4.9, I see the following key events in 
modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp

```
enum
{
    EVENT_MOUSEMOVE      =0,
    EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN    =1,
    EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN    =2,
    EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN    =3,
    EVENT_LBUTTONUP      =4,
    EVENT_RBUTTONUP      =5,
    EVENT_MBUTTONUP      =6,
    EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK  =7,
    EVENT_RBUTTONDBLCLK  =8,
    EVENT_MBUTTONDBLCLK  =9
};
```

So, check your source file whether the event name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

replace this :

```
imshow("amin",image);
waitKey(0);
```

with :

```
while(true){
imshow("amin",image);
waitKey(1);}  // 1ms
```